# OCR that delivers overlay HTML to an Image?

Tags: html, ocr

I am looking for an OCR software that renders overlay HTML to an image. I am currently using some unnamed product. It has an OCR function, which will do an inline OCR of a PDF document with images.

The inline OCR is very handy, it allows to search the PDF document with images for text. Also text can be directly highlighted in the document, the OCR text is aligned with the underlying image. Unfortunately I can neiter export nor store the inline OCR from within the unnamed product.

Is there some other software around which can perform and export an inline OCR? I would be especially interested in exporting into an HTML consisting of positioned paragraphs which are aligned with the underlying image.

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404805/ocr-and-the-location-of-the-image-where-the-scanned-document-came-from

Comment: I am also interested in this problem. (I assume "unnamed" means it is proprietary, not that you don't know what it is). Are you training the OCR or are you assuming it will interpret against a given character set. Would shapecatcher.com help you - it runs bitmaps against a standard Unicode glyph set?

Comment: Thanks. I am producing a completely OpenSource solution to extracting information (bitbucket.org/petermr/pdf2svg-dev and bitbucket.org/petermr/svg2xml-devfrom PDF but haven't yet done very much on the image/OCR part. I would expect to address ANSI first, but don't hold your breath.

Answer (score 4):

I've found the Google Drive API to be helpful when requiring OCR. It attempts to preserve the format of the document which of course can be exported as HTML.

Take a look at the following links:

- https://support.google.com/drive/answer/176692?hl=en
- https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

I have a possible solution for you. But, this particular solution has some drawbacks, that might hinder you end goal.

First convert image file at to pdf : http://finereader.abbyyonline.com 
Then convert the pdf to html at http://document.online-convert.com/convert-to-html

This solution works for things about the size of paper, and the final result has the html with the image overlay, If all you want is the html with the image formatting just make the images fully transparent.